# pandas rearranging a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is as follows:

```
Honda [edit]
Accord (4 models)
Civic  (4 models)
Pilot  (3 models)
Toyota [edit]
Prius  (4 models)
Highlander (3 models)
Ford [edit]
Explorer (2 models)
```

I am looking to reshape it such that I get a resulting 2 column data frame as follows:

```
 Honda     Accord
 Honda     Civic
 Honda     Pilot
 Toyota    Prius
 Toyota    Highlander
```

and so on.
I tried str.split trying to split between edits, but was not successful. Any suggestions are most appreciated! Python newbie here...so apologies if this has been addressed before.
Thanks!

So far I tried

```
     maker=car['T'].str.extract('(.*\[edit\])', expand=False).str.replace('\[edit\]',"")
```

This gives me the list of Makers: Honda, Toyota and Ford. However I am stuck at finding a way to extract the models between the makers to create the 2 col DF.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Put code in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is to extract the car column first, then to get the maker.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['model'] = df['T'].apply(lambda x: x.split(
    '(')[0].strip() if x.count('(') > 0 else np.NaN)

df['maker'] = df['T'].apply(lambda x: x.split('[')[0].strip(
) if x.count('[') > 0 else np.NaN).fillna(method="ffill")

df = df.dropna().drop('T', axis=1).reindex(
    columns=['maker', 'model']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The first line of the code extracts all the cars by using split and strip string operations if the entry contained `'('`, it assigns `NaN` otherwise, we use `NaN` so that we can delete those rows after finding the makers.
At this stage the data frame `df` will be:

```
+----+-----------------------+------------+
|    | T                     | model      |
|----+-----------------------+------------|
|  0 | Honda [edit]          | nan        |
|  1 | Accord (4 models)     | Accord     |
|  2 | Civic  (4 models)     | Civic      |
|  3 | Pilot  (3 models)     | Pilot      |
|  4 | Toyota [edit]         | nan        |
|  5 | Prius  (4 models)     | Prius      |
|  6 | Highlander (3 models) | Highlander |
|  7 | Ford [edit]           | nan        |
|  8 | Explorer (2 models)   | Explorer   |
+----+-----------------------+------------+
```

The second line does the same but for `'['` records, here the `NaNs` are used to fill forward the empty maker cells using [fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
At this stage the data frame `df` will be:

```
+----+-----------------------+------------+---------+
|    | T                     | model      | maker   |
|----+-----------------------+------------+---------|
|  0 | Honda [edit]          | nan        | Honda   |
|  1 | Accord (4 models)     | Accord     | Honda   |
|  2 | Civic  (4 models)     | Civic      | Honda   |
|  3 | Pilot  (3 models)     | Pilot      | Honda   |
|  4 | Toyota [edit]         | nan        | Toyota  |
|  5 | Prius  (4 models)     | Prius      | Toyota  |
|  6 | Highlander (3 models) | Highlander | Toyota  |
|  7 | Ford [edit]           | nan        | Ford    |
|  8 | Explorer (2 models)   | Explorer   | Ford    |
+----+-----------------------+------------+---------+
```

The third line drops the extra records and rearrange the columns as well as reset the index

```
|    | maker   | model      |
|----+---------+------------|
|  0 | Honda   | Accord     |
|  1 | Honda   | Civic      |
|  2 | Honda   | Pilot      |
|  3 | Toyota  | Prius      |
|  4 | Toyota  | Highlander |
|  5 | Ford    | Explorer   |
```

EDIT:

A more "pandorable" version (I am fond of one liners)

```
df = df['T'].str.extractall('(.+)\[|(.+)\(').apply(
    lambda x: x.ffill() 
    if x.name==0 
    else x).dropna(subset=[1]).reset_index(
    drop=True).rename(columns={1:'Model',0:'Maker'})
```

the above works as follows
[`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) will return a DataFrame with two columns; column `0` corresponding to the group in the regex extracted using the first group`'(.+)\['` i.e. the maker records ending with; and column `1`, corresponding to the second group i.e. `'(.+)\('`, [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is used to iterate through the columns, the column named `0` will be modified to propagate the 'Maker' values forward via [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) and column `1` will be left as is. [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) is then used with subset `1` to remove all rows where the value in column `1` is `NaN`, [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is used to drop the mult-index `extractall` generates. finally the columns are renamed using [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and a correspondence dictionary

[image]

Another one liner (func ;))

```
 df['T'].apply(lambda line: [line.split('[')[0],None] if line.count('[') 
                       else [None,line.split('(')[0].strip()]
              ).apply(pd.Series
                      ).rename(
                            columns={0:'Maker',1:'Model'}
                        ).apply(
                         lambda col: col.ffill() if col.name == 'Maker' 
                         else col).dropna(
                                    subset=['Model']
                                    ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I think you can use `None` instead of `np.NaN` in the `else` part of the `if` statements in of both `lambda`s. I haven't tested it though

Comment: Perfect thanks everyone! both worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html). Then remove rows which contains `[edit]` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and mask by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for create unique `index` and last remove original column `col` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df['model'] = df.col.str.extract('(.*)\[edit\]', expand=False).ffill()
df['type'] = df.col.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)', expand=False)
df = df[~df.col.str.contains('\[edit\]')].reset_index(drop=True).drop('col', axis=1)
print (df)
     model        type
0   Honda       Accord
1   Honda        Civic
2   Honda        Pilot
3  Toyota        Prius
4  Toyota   Highlander
5    Ford     Explorer
```

Another solution use `extract` and [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) for create new column by condition and last use `boolean indexing` again:

```
df['type'] = df.col.str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)', expand=False)
df['model'] = df['type'].where(df.col.str.contains('\[edit\]')).ffill()
df = df[df.type != df.model].reset_index(drop=True).drop('col', axis=1)
print (df)
         type   model
0      Accord   Honda
1       Civic   Honda
2       Pilot   Honda
3       Prius  Toyota
4  Highlander  Toyota
5    Explorer    Ford
```

EDIT:

If need `type` with `spaces` in text, use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) all values from ( to the end, also remove spaces by `s\+`:

```
print (df)
                             col
0                   Honda [edit]
1              Accord (4 models)
2              Civic  (4 models)
3              Pilot  (3 models)
4                  Toyota [edit]
5              Prius  (4 models)
6          Highlander (3 models)
7                    Ford [edit]
8  Ford Expedition XL (2 models)

df['model'] = df.col.str.extract('(.*)\[edit\]', expand=False).ffill()
df['type'] = df.col.str.replace(r'\s+\(.+$', '')
df = df[~df.col.str.contains('\[edit\]')].reset_index(drop=True).drop('col', axis=1)
print (df)
     model                type
0   Honda               Accord
1   Honda                Civic
2   Honda                Pilot
3  Toyota                Prius
4  Toyota           Highlander
5    Ford   Ford Expedition XL
```

Comment: Exactly, col is name of column, I try explain it more, give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks for the info. A couple of questions: 1) Could you explain a bit more on the third statement? Also I presume, col refers to a column name col in data frame df, correct? Lastly if we had a model that has a space like Ford Expedition XL, how can I account for the space? Thanks!

Comment: sorry about the repeated comment, for some reason it did not show me your response when I refreshed :)

Comment: I add solution, plese check it. Also you can upvote too - click to small triangle above `0` above accepting mark. Thanks.